# Running C++ client/server for parallel processing using MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

#### Introduction

In order to parallelize numerical integration in C++, I want to use a client/server approach on my local machine. For this, I am using the [message passing interface for C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).

#### My code

So I first tried a hello world setup, where I will send a message from the client to the server. For this I have two files in the same directory. Here is the code for the Server, `server.cpp`:

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int size, rank, msg;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MPI_Comm client;
    MPI_Status status;
    char portname[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, portname);
    printf("portname: %s\n", portname);
    MPI_Comm_accept(portname, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &client);
    printf("client connected\n");
    MPI_Recv(&msg, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, client, &status);
    printf("msg: %d\n", msg);
    MPI_Comm_free(&client);
    MPI_Close_port(portname);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Here is the code for the Client, `client.cpp`:

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int size, rank;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MPI_Comm server;
    int msg, tag, dest;
    char portname[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    if (argc >= 2){
        printf("Trying connect to %s\n", argv[1]);
        strcpy(portname, argv[1]);
        MPI_Comm_connect(portname, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &server);
        msg = 42; tag = 0; dest = 0;
        MPI_Send(&msg, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag, server);
        MPI_Comm_disconnect(&server);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

#### How I tried to run my code

I compiled both client and server using `mpiCC -g -Wall -o client.out client.cpp` and `mpiCC -g -Wall -o server.out server.cpp` respectively.

Now I open two different terminals and I use `mpirun -np 1 ./server.out` in the first terminal to run the server. This gives me the portname so I can use `mpirun -np 1 ./client.out <PORTNAME>` in the second terminal to run the client. However, I get the following error:

```
Trying connect to <PORTNAME>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The user has called an operation involving MPI_Connect and/or MPI_Accept
that spans multiple invocations of mpirun. This requires the support of
the ompi-server tool, which must be executing somewhere that can be
accessed by all participants.

Please ensure the tool is running, and provide each mpirun with the MCA
parameter "pmix_server_uri" pointing to it.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Your application has invoked an MPI function that is not supported in
this environment.

  MPI function: MPI_Comm_connect
  Reason:       Underlying runtime environment does not support accept/connect functionality
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ubuntu-workstation:00101] *** An error occurred in MPI_Comm_connect
[ubuntu-workstation:00101] *** reported by process [23056836,0]
[ubuntu-workstation:00101] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[ubuntu-workstation:00101] *** MPI_ERR_INTERN: internal error
[ubuntu-workstation:00101] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[ubuntu-workstation:00101] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

#### What I tried

I found  [this blog post](http://silveiraneto.net/estudos/mpi-client-server/), where a very similar error occurs.

It seems I only have to start this ominous "ompi-server tool", however, being new to MPI, I have no idea where to find this tool and how to start it... So how can I fix the error?

Comment: Which version of Open MPI is that?

Comment: @HristoIliev Here are the first two lines of the output of `ompi_info` : `Package: Debian OpenMPI \n Open MPI: 3.1.3`

Comment: I have a couple of answers here regarding the client/server mechanism in older versions of Open MPI, but things have changed a bit since then. Let me check how it is with v3.1. In the mean time, why do you need client/server functionality? Can't you do the processing using simple MPI job with a bunch of ranks and simply let rank 0 be the server?

Comment: The client/server feature of MPI is widely unused (it's even listed under "Other functionality" in the chapter about process creation in the MPI specification), which is why you end up in a situation that its support by one of the major MPI implementations is badly broken. The main reason is that it makes little sense without provisions for fault tolerance, which is still lacking in MPI. So, I'd recommend that you follow a different set of online exercises :)

Comment: Unless you cannot launch both client and server at the same time, you can use the MPMD syntax `mpirun -np 1 ./server : -np 1 ./client`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that the latest version of Open MPI that has working accept/connect functionality is Open MPI 1.6.5. Starting with v1.7 the support is broken and with ORTE 2.x the required support is missing altogether and its implementation is low priority as indicated in the [issue](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/3458). You should either somehow implement your solution without client/server functionality, downgrade to Open MPI 1.6.5, or simply switch to MPICH or Intel MPI. The latter is now free for use as part of oneAPI and I just tested that your code works with it after fixing the typo in `client.cpp` (`server` instead of `servidor`).

Comment: Alright thank you! I'll accept it once I tried it out tomorrow if I can get it to work

Comment: If you install Intel MPI without removing Open MPI, keep in mind that the C++ wrapper there is called `mpicxx`. If you use `mpiCC`, it will still be the one from Open MPI. And the port names seem to contain `$` signs, so you need to properly escape the string on the command line.

Comment: Ok so I have now installed Intel's MPI from https://software.seek.intel.com/performance-libraries and recompiled both files with `mpicxx`... But I still get the same error? Is there a different `mpirun` command for Intel's MPI than for Open MPI ?

Comment: Another update: I have uninstalled Intel's MPI as well as Open MPI and I have installed MPICH. Now everything works as expected 

Comment: Are you sure your program is linked with Intel MPI? Even if you are using the wrong MPI launcher, you should not be getting the same error as Intel MPI's errors look completely differently. Use `ldd ./server.out` to see if you are linking against the right libraries. Also, the launcher in Intel MPI is called `mpiexec` and I'd recommend that you use that name wherever possible as it is a bit more "standard". Same applies for Open MPI - its launcher name is `orterun` and it is symlinked as both `mpirun` and `mpiexec`.

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure that `mpirun` was still linked to Open MPI. Anyways, this doesn't matter now since I removed Open MPI. Also, thank you for telling me to escape the dollars, that probably saved me half an hour of frustration 